# Unable to Successfully Pass Parameters to xsl:call-template

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a generic template I've designed with 2 params `title` and `category`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:param name="category" />
    <xsl:param name="title" />
    <xsl:template name="test-group">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value=of select="$title" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="$category" />
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the parent template I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:include href="templates/generic_template.xsl" />
    ...
    <xsl:call-template name="test-group">
        <xsl:with-param name="category" select="'animals'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'DOGS'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, when the transform completes title and category are blank. I'm using FOP 2.0 so I'm not sure if this is a known shortcoming.

Comment: The xsl:param should be inside xsl:template.

Comment: @pticawr make that the answer and you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a `xsl:template` that takes parameters, the parameter names used within the `xsl:template` should be declared using `xls:param` elements nested within.

```
<xsl:template name="test-group">
  <xsl:param name="category" />
  <xsl:param name="title" />
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

The parameters being attached to the `xsl:template` and not the `xsl:stylesheet`.
This is similar to when calling the template with `xsl:call-template`, except you are specifying the values instead using `xsl:with-param`.